# Why window.open acts differently in each browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

`Javascript`'s window.open open new tab in Chrome and Firefox but open new window in Safari.Why it act like this?

Comment: This may help: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html

Comment: thanks@CharlSteynberg